# Insert into Table A if key exists in Table B

Tags: sql

Using BBj DBMS (it's weird). I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`. `TableA` has columns `Name` and `TableBId`. I want to make certain that `TableBId` exists in `TableB` prior to inserting this new record into my table. I'm taking a blind insert (VIA a REST call) and am looking into making as few calls to the DB as possible.

Currently I have something along this lines of

```
INSERT INTO tablea (name, tablebid)
VALUES('Steven', '100')
```

I've tried appending

```
SELECT tablea.tablebid
FROM tablea join tableb
```

Without any luck

**Edit**: After suggestions, I'm trying.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (field1, field2, field3, tableBId, field5)
SELECT 'info', 'info2', 'info3', tableBId, 'info5'
FROM tableB WHERE tableBId = '01'
```

However, I'm getting a duplicate key in write. To reiterate, I'm trying to make sure that tableBId exists in TableB, and if it doesn't I want the insert function to fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tablea (name, tablebid)
SELECT 'Steven',tableid
FROM tableB
Where tableId=100
```

..

```
INSERT INTO trafficdetail (companycode, developmentcode, casenumber, questionnumber, answercode) 
SELECT '100', '1A', '000001300', questionnumber, '20' 
from trafficquesmast where questionnumber = '01'
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the from, so I may have the post this question to their support staff. Any other syntax you can think of?

Comment: Moving away from the SSCE.     
UNABLE TO EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT: Syntax error in SQL statement at 'INSERT INTO trafficdetail (companycode, developmentcode, casenumber, questionnumber, answercode)
values ('100', '1A', '000001300', questionnumber, '20')
<<<<from>>>> trafficquesmast
where questionnumber = '01''.

Comment: "UNABLE TO EXECUTE SQL STATEMENT: Problem updating row: Duplicate key in write." Mind you, the only duplicate key would be the one in trafficquesmast. I imagine it's not a problem in this situation that company, development, casenumber, and answercodes are all not columns within trafficquesmast?

Comment: the key column in traffic detail must not contain value as being supplied from select query

Comment: That makes sense as to why it's failing, but traffic detail will contain that column multiple times. The entire record will be unique, but I need to know that questionnumber is a valid entry in traffic questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tablea (name, tablebid)
SELECT 'Steven', id
FROM tableb
where id = @id
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the from, so I may have the post this question to their support staff. Any other syntax you can think of?

Comment: Post your sql. Do you have an extra comma at the end of the last column name?